# how could i return a ref to an int from a struct?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I basically need a reference to a private value type that is inside a value type.

I have the following struct:

```
public struct someStruct
{
    public enum Type { AA = 0, BB = 1, CC = 1 } //this was because i first wanted to change
                                                //the switch with an array of refs but that 
                                                //also does not work in c#
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    public int GetTypeStrength(Type type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case Type.AA: return a;
            case Type.BB: return b;
            case Type.CC: return c;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

But I wanted to rewrite GetTypeStrength to something like:

```
public int GetTypeStrength(Type type)
{
    return Get(type)

ref int Get(Type type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case Type.AA: return ref a;
        case Type.BB: return ref b;
        case Type.CC: return ref c;
        default: /*throw exception*/;
    }
}
```

To have a better time writing more methods,
but because of structs I cannot return refs.
Also I found a workaround to this using extension methods, but with that I would need to make the fields public thus break encapsulation, unless something like the friend keyword existed but from what I read it doesn't exist in c#.

So is there any way to make this work?
Im working with unity and it needs to be called multiple times per frame so reflection is not an option.

[Edit]
Here is an example of things i would like to add:

```
public static someStruct operator +(someStruct sstr, Type type)
{
    sstr.Get(type)++;
    return sstr;
}
```

Comment: Change the struct to a class

Comment: And why do you want that? Especially since you are not returning `ref` from `GetTypeStrength`. Please provide a full sample explaining that.

Comment: @Absinthe its not a good option, for my case, I need it to be a value type. I also would want to know how it could be achieved to have a better understanding of C#.

Comment: @GuruStron While GetTypeStrength() does not use the ref i want to add operators and it would be used there

Comment: TBH it is a bit weird design. Why you don't want to turn `someStruct` into a class (especially since you have considered using arrays)?

Comment: @GuruStron the main reason i went for arrays is because i want this struct handled as a value type and otherwise i would need to tell the team "hey remember that you mostly need to copy the value" and could cause bugs because of that.

Comment: @Mtreitor TBH sounds a bit strange but without seeing the whole codebase it is hard to tell. Also I would consider using the immutable records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I found a workaround to this using extension methods

From pure technical standpoint of view you don't need extension methods per se, you can go with static ones, though it will require changes to the invocation:

```
public struct SomeStruct
{
    // ...
    public int GetTypeStrength(Type type)
    {
        return Get(ref this, type);
    }
    
    static ref int Get(ref someStruct s, Type type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case Type.AA: return ref s.a;
            case Type.BB: return ref s.b;
            case Type.CC: return ref s.c;
            default: throw new Exception()/*throw exception*/;
        }
    }

    public static someStruct operator +(someStruct sstr, Type type)
    {
        Get(ref sstr, type)++;
        return sstr;
    }
}
```

P.S.

I recommend to change the enum name from `Type` to prevent the name collision with the build-in type.